# How to set attributes for a custom UI element?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to program a very simple calculator for iOS. I have a storyboard in XCode with several buttons, which are actually my own subclass:

```
@interface CalcButton : UIButton
{
  int digit;
}
@property int digit;
@end
```

In the "Identity Inspector" I was able to select a "Custom Class" for by buttons. How would I now set the `digit` attribute for my buttons?

Comment: you should #import "CalcButton.h"

Comment: oh... where would that import go?

Comment: How would just importing it do anything. There is a lot more for it then just that.

Comment: In code, in storyboard or both?

Comment: where you want to set/access your custom button, normally the view controller associated with your storyboard object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to set this property in storyboard.

You can do it in code by creating outlet from your custom class (CalcButton) in storyboard to the class (mostly UIViewController or UIView) which own this controls and in your code you can do it for example in viewDidLoad method:

```
self.yourCalcButtonOutlet.digit = 2;
```

Comment: Is this the best way of implementing these buttons? Or is there a better way than subclassing ``UIButton``?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. You can, for example, use tag property of UIButton object to store int number and in this scenario you don't need declare the custom class. It all depends what are you trying to do.